# Visual Studio doesn't give option to Migrate EF Database

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, publish

This is driving me nuts.  I've got the same code base on two machines, both cloned from the same repository in GitHub.  My workstation gives me the option to publish the EF Migration:

[image]

My Azure-based virtual server does not:

[image]

Both instances are running the latest Visual Studio 2019 (16.4.3).  What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, that was painful.  It turns out that when you upgrade to .NET Core 3.1.1 from .NET Core 3.1.0 (or probably earlier), there is a configuration file for the tools that isn't upgraded as well.  In the hidden directory **.config**, there is a file called **dotnet-tools.json**.  This file needs to be updated by hand to:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "isRoot": true,
  "tools": {
    "dotnet-ef": {
      "version": "3.1.1",
      "commands": [
        "dotnet-ef"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The 'version' line needs to be updated to 3.1.1 to be compatible with the packages (I guess).

I don't have a real good explanation of why it works on my desktop, but it could be that I had .NET Core 3.1.0 installed on the machine at one time, whereas my virtual server is a clean install of the OS.